# Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

Tags: tcpclient

I am developing a client-server chat application and I have encountered the following exception when I close the client window.

Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: any solution about it?

Answer (score 4):

If you call a .Close() on any of you readers or writers to the underlying stream. and try to use that reader or writer afterwards, then you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

after all `.Close();` calls, also close threads that call these readers/writers. Like in [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/512588-c-networking-threading/) similar code under discussion, the problem can be solved by simply adding `.Abort();` in two places where `.Close();` for streams are called:

```
            swSender.Close();
            srReceiver.Close();
            tcpServer.Close();
            thrMessaging.Abort(); // this needed to be added to solve the problem
```